# How to use "DISTINCT ON" in conjunction with Arel / ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel, distinct-on

I have a `Message` ActiveRecord Model and I want to select all messages that have a distinct `conversation_partner_id`. I'm currently specifying the `DISTINCT ON` clause as a string but I was wondering if it could be provided as an `Arel` expression instead and whether there would be a benefit. My statement looks as follows:

```
Message.select('DISTINCT ON ("messages"."conversation_partner_id") messages.*').from(t)
```

where `t` is a union of the `messages` table and specified as a somewhat complex `Arel` expression. I leave it out as it is independent of the `SELECT` issue and works just fine.

The following code does **not** work:

```
Message.select([
  Arel::Nodes::DistinctOn.new(Message.arel_table[:conversation_partner_id]),
  Message.arel_table[Arel.star]
]).from(t)
```

It results in malformed SQL as it places a comma after the `DISTINCT ON ()` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("messages"."conversation_partner_id"), "messages".* ...
                                                         ^
```

Answer (score 5):

If you try this:

```
Message.arel_table
       .project(Arel.star)
       .distinct_on(Message.arel_table[:conversation_partner_id])
       .to_sql
```

You get this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ( \"messages\".\"conversation_partner_id\" ) * FROM ...
```

Comment: `DISTINCT ON` is not implemented for all databases, and only works for Postgres AFAIK, and arel didn't implement it either.